# ReactJS: How to change value of specific field in an object array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { items: this.props.items }
    // items props is: [{'id':'73','foo':'bar'},{'id':'45','foo':'bar'}]
}

onClick () {
    const myArray = this.state.items
    const ids = ['45', '73']
    ids.forEach((id, index) => {
        myArray.find(x => x.id === id).foo = index
    })
}
```

I need to change `foo` value to index value. So the result should look like

```
myArray = [{'id':'73','foo': 1},{'id':'45','foo': 0}]
```

I think with this, I do get the current value, but the syntax is wrong to change its value:

```
myArray.find(x => x.id === '45').foo = 'new'
```

I do get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'foo' of object '#<Object>'`

Comment: [No thats fine...](http://jsbin.com/rovonodedo/edit?console)

Comment: Works fine in the console.

Comment: The problem must be elsewhere, [this demo in react](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-phyrnk) works just fine.

Comment: @Ted: I'm setting the items state via props: `this.state = { items: this.props.items }` because I'll modify items as shown in the post. But with that I do get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'foo' of object '#<Object>'` - also for your code.

Comment: @user3142695, then without seeing the code, I would suggest deep cloning the array, modifying the value in the clone, and setting state with the cloned array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to change the property you want:

```js
const myArray = [{ id: '73', foo: 'bar' }, { id: '45', foo: 'new' }, { id: '46', foo: 'do not change me' }]

const ids = ['45', '73']

const newArr = myArray.map(item => {
  if (ids.indexOf(item.id) !== -1) {
    return {
      ...item,
      foo: 'newFooValue'
    }
  }
  
  return item
})

console.log(newArr)
```

It's also important to note that change object properties directly (such as `myArray.find(x => x.id === '45').foo`) is not a good practice though.

In case `items`is in you `state`, you can simple change it by:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
   items: prevState.items.map(/* same code as in the snippet above */),
}))
```

Comment: That sounds great. Is it possible to modify multiple objects? I've updated the post. Please have a look at it. I need to change `foo` value of each object with the ID of the ids-array. Maybe I can avoid the forEach-loop? Maybe I can use `indexOf` inside of `map`?

Comment: @user3142695 sure you can :) I've just updated my answer. Hope that helps now :)